# How to do integration testing when using Mybatis and different DB for Integration testing and development

Tags: java, mysql, integration-testing, h2, mybatis

I am using MyBatis for developing my application . Now i have stumbled upon a situation where the sql query should return last inserted id to me ,

I am using MySql for development and H2 DB for Integration Testing .

In MySql we use last_insert_id() function to get this id but in H2 DB we use currval() functiton . Even if i use sequence in MySql still this syntax would be different .

The question now is how am i suppose to write integration testing code . Since same query what i have written for the development is used for integration testing . what i should do in this kind of situation

Comment: `last_insert_id()` appears to be a MySQL function, not Oracle.

Comment: sorry i was using mysql not oracle DB . didn't know since i didn't configure Dbeaver

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL, based on either database type, or maybe other variable that you have available (e.g. an environment variable with the current profile).
An example from the documentation:

```
<insert id="insert">
  <selectKey keyProperty="id" resultType="int" order="BEFORE">
    <if test="_databaseId == 'oracle'">
      select seq_users.nextval from dual
    </if>
    <if test="_databaseId == 'db2'">
      select nextval for seq_users from sysibm.sysdummy1"
    </if>
  </selectKey>
  insert into users values (#{id}, #{name})
</insert>
```

Refer to the [documentation here](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html).

Comment: i believe integration testing should be done  on code that is database agnostic. and our code should work for both data bases  .

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Spring boot, you can try to put the below property in your test application.properties file. Just one line:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:test;MODE=MySQL
```

The keyword is MODE=MySQL, and it works for me.